# Load data from server in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have made a form. When filling all the fields and hitting search button under it should show data from server in suitable view. The data also contain image with it . Image should come on left side with a fixed size and some information about image beside it and when user scroll down the data automatically appear under each other from server. I'm using POST method to search the required data. Can any one help me how it would happen that when i hit a search button it shows data in table view.?The data should dispatch queue before it appear on uitable view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily by combination of **Pagination** on huge amount of data fetching and loading the images from the existing chunks with **SDWebImage**

check out the following Blog post - by ***`iOSCodeGuide`***

[How to Loading Large amount of Data / Images in iOS in 2 Simple Steps - By **iOSCodeGuide**](http://ioscodeguide.blogspot.in/2017/05/loading-large-amount-of-data-images-in.html)

Comment: is there any other blog related to the issue? @IOS dev

Comment: I've followed this blog, as it is combination of Pagination on huge amount of data fetching and loading the images from the existing chunks with SDWebImage it would be very fast.. if no images in ur app ignore sd web and follow pagination

Comment: actually I'm confused that i have to give fixed pattern to it . i mean a fixed size image view where new images load from service and date beside it like its name and location there data should appear in front of them. how cani do this with this blog? @IOS dev